# Can't hide the Blog Tools web part programmatically on blog site

Tags: web-part, splimitedwebpartmanager

I have an event receiver that modifies some web parts when a new blog site is created:

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = clientWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager(SPUtility.ConcatUrls(clientWeb.Url, "default.aspx"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart in wpManager.WebParts)
    {
        switch (webPart.Title)
        {
            case "About this blog":
                webPart.Hidden = true;
                wpManager.SaveChanges(webPart);
                break;
            case "Links":
                webPart.Hidden = true;
                wpManager.SaveChanges(webPart);
                break;
            case "Blog Tools":
                webPart.Hidden = true;
                wpManager.SaveChanges(webPart);
                break;
            case "Posts":
                webPart.Title = "Blog Posts";
                webPart.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.TitleOnly;
                wpManager.SaveChanges(webPart);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code hides About this blog, Links and changes the name of Posts but I can't get it to hide the Blog Tools web part, when I debug the code the name is Blog Tools so I can find it but why doesn't it get hidden?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Blog Tools web part ([Blog Admin web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.blogadminwebpart.aspx)) the [Hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.hidden.aspx) property cannot be set to **true** explicitly. This property is initialized during *OnLoad* event and depends on the following conditions:

- does the current user has a [permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx) to add items to Posts list
- web part [IsStandalone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bhddc9y6) Property value

So, in order to hide this web part another options should be considered. For example, it could be hidden on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SPLimitedWebPartManager` you could use the ASP.NET controls collection to find a control of type `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BlogAdminWebPart` and set `Visible = false`.

To find the control in question you need to start with `this.Page.Controls` and do a recursive loop through all controls until you found it (note: this might put quite some execution time on each page load, so you might probably want to apply a smarter way to locate the WebPart control if you can be sure to find it always at the same WebPart zone/place).

Put all that code into a SharePoint `AdditionalPlaceHead` control and create a feature which staples it to the `SPWeb` of your choice.

Been there, done that for a couple of years now (even hiding the whole WebPart zone containing the `BlogAdminWebPart`).

Comment: Thanks for your post, had already marked Vadim's answer though